# How to cite online publication with address?

Tags: bibtex, citing

Code BibTeX entry

```
@misc{ stat_suomi_90_14, 
   author = "Tilastokeskus",
   title = "4. Vuosineljännes 2014, Liitekuvio 12. Sähkön tuonti ja vienti 1990–2014*", 
   address = "Helsinki", 
   url = "http://www.stat.fi/til/ehk/2014/04/ehk_2014_04_2015-03-23_kuv_012_fi.html", 
   note = "[Online; visited 6-May-2015]"
}
```

and in TeX document at the end

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{task}
```

which gives

[image]

where no fields `address` and `url` information. 
I need the address and url pieces of information in the cite.

**How can you cite better to this web publication?**

Comment: Do you have to use the `ieeetr` bibliography style, or are you free to use one of the more modern styles distributed by the IEEE?

Comment: Your choices: (1) use an entry type that prints those fields (perhaps `@online`?); (2) use a `.bst` that uses those fields for the `@misc` entry type; (3) copy, rename, and then modify the `ieeetr.bst` so the `@misc` entry type prints those fields; (4) dump all the information you want to get printed into the `note` field and format it all by hand; or (5) switch to `biblatex` (which opens a whole new vista of possibilities, but doesn't necessarily make it easy to get an `ieeetr` clone without doing the work yourself).

Comment: @Mico I am free to use more modern styles distributed by IEEE. Which of those can be options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ieeetr` bibliography style is one of the original BibTeX styles. It dates back to (at least) the early 1990s. As such, maybe unsurprisingly, it's not programmed to do anything with a `url` field.

I suggest you use the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style instead. It is much newer and does know how to process the `url` field. It also doesn't ignore the `address` field. If you follow this approach, you should load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`. In addition, you may want to drop the string "Online" from the `note` field, since the string "[Online]. Available:" is prefixed to the `url` field by the IEEEtranN style.

A separate remark: I'm afraid I don't understand a single word of Finnish, but I suspect that one or more of the words `Vuosineljännes`, `Liitekuvio`, and `Sähkön` should not be converted to lowercase by BibTeX. If this hunch is correct, you should encase the words in curly braces, to exempt them from the "sentence style" conversion that's applied by the IEEEtranN bibliography style to the contents of `title` fields.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{task.bib}
@misc{ stat_suomi_90_14, 
   author = "Tilastokeskus",
   title = "4. Vuosineljännes 2014, Liitekuvio 12. Sähkön tuonti ja vienti 1990–2014*", 
   address = "Helsinki", 
   url = "http://www.stat.fi/til/ehk/2014/04/ehk_2014_04_2015-03-23_kuv_012_fi.html", 
   note = "visited 6-May-2015"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{task}
\end{document}
```